# How to consume token based node api in to angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, token

I am creating token at login time with node.js:

```
apiRoutes.put('/login', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result){
       if(result){
        var token=jwt.encode(user,config.secret); 
        return res.json({success: true, token:'JWT' +token});         
      }else{
        return res.json("Incorrect Email and Password")
      }
    })
  })
});
```

now I am trying to show user dashboard page with `/dashboard` route and I am doing something like below:

```
apiRoutes.get('/dashboard',function(req, res) {
  var token=getToken(req.headers); 
  if(token){
    var decode=jwt.decode(token, config.secret); 
    console.log(decode);
    User.findOne({name:decode.name}, function(err, user){
      if(err){res.json(err)}
        if(!user){
          return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'Authentication Failed'})
        }else{
          res.json({success:true, msg:'Welcome in the Area &nbsp;' +user.name+'!' })
        }
    })
  }else{
    return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'No Token Found'})
  } 
  });

 getToken = function (head) {
  if (head && head.authorization) { 
    var parted = head.authorization.split(' '); 
    if (parted.length == 2) {  
      return parted[1];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

In `postman` when I hit `/dashboard` api its working good. and printing the output `success:true, msg:'Welcome in the Area  Admin`;
But when in angular js I am consuming this api then output in node console is `null`. 
Below is my angular function to consume api

```
 app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){ 
        $http.get('/api/dashboard').success(function(res){
            $scope.result=res;  
        })
    })
```

I want to know how to consume token based route in angular. I know above given angular function is not right. Please let me know the right code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the header for the `$http.get()`. Here is how you should do:

```
$http.get('/api/dashboard', {
  headers: {
    // Set header for the request here
    authorization: token
  }
})
.success(function(res) {
  // Success
});
```

Comment: token is not defined

Comment: No, `token` is from the response from your `$http.put('/api/login')`. I just abstracted that part because I assumed that you already did that and save the respond in `token` variable.

Comment: yes I did... Like as

$scope.login=function(){
  $http.put('/api/login', $scope.new).then(function(response){
   $cookieStore.put('token', response.data.token);
   $cookieStore.put('currentUser', $scope.new.email);
   $rootScope.token=response.data.token;
   $rootScope.currentUser=$scope.new.email;
         $location.path('/dashboard');
         $scope.loggindata=response; 
  },function(err){ 
   alert('Incorrect Email and password');
  });
 }

Comment: I see you dit put `token` in the `cookies` and in `$rootScope`. So, add this line before the `$http.get(..);`:  `var token = $rootScope.token`

Comment: var token = $rootScope.token;
 $http.get('/api/dashboard',{ headers: {authorization: token }}).success(function(res){
  $scope.result=res;  
 }) 

 In browser console its error `/api/dashboard` (403) forbidden

Comment: That because the `apiRoutes.get('/dashboard', ...);` return a responce with `403` code. Check ` getToken = function (head)` code block.  Can you log the `head`?

Comment: `head` is returning `token`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129509/discussion-between-triet-dang-and-saurabh-sharma).

Comment: Yes... Now its working..... but user data is always undefined
means getToken function is working good... now in angular function console.log($scope.result)  is printing success message.
now only problem is that when I am trying to get data {{result.name}} in page then its undefined